# .htaccess allow image to display directly

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have many files including images, php& js scripts and subfolders.
I need to redirect to index.php for any uri using .htaccess.
for example:

```
www.example.com/test should be redirect to index.php
```

But images should not be redirected to index.php. Instead it should be printed directly in browser.
For example:

```
www.example.com/sample.jpg should display sample.jpg.
```

I am using following codes in .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

**Can someone explain how to allow image to display?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add conditions before your rule to skip image/css/js filesdirectories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: But need to redirect any uri to index.php as if file exist or not exist.   If it is .jpg/.gif file, it should be displayed in browser without redirection.